# is the adress value return by map.LoadOrStore the same as the input in case of nested maps?

Tags: go, type-assertion

I'm doing a nested [sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) but I wonder if I can save some few lines of code if the value returned by `LoadOrStore`  is the same as the input in case of a map, I mean this:

```
var mapa sync.Map
mapaInterFace, ok := sessiones.LoadOrStore(userID,mapa)
if ok {
    mapa,ok=mapaInterFace.(sync.Map)
    if !ok{
        return errors.New("type assertion")
    }
}
```

If `mapa` were the same as the returned by `LoadOrStore` when the value is stored, I can immediately use it, but if not I have to add after the previous code, the type assertion:

```
mapa,ok=mapaInterFace.(sync.Map)
    if !ok{
        return errors.New("type assertion")
    }
```

and doing some often it can make some ugly code

Update: `sessiones` is type sync.Map

Comment: For starters, you can't use a `sync.Map` value, since it cannot be copied. This code will fail `go vet`

Comment: but I can use it's pointer because sync.Map it's a struct

Comment: yes, that's the point. `sync.Map` is a struct containing data structures that can't be safely copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explain later, you should use pointers for the `sync.Map` types. Therefore, we can simplify to:

```
var mapa, mapb = new(sync.Map), new(sync.Map)
var key string

if actual, loaded := mapa.LoadOrStore(key, mapb); loaded {
    if maps, ok := actual.(*sync.Map); ok {
        mapb = maps
    } else {
        // handle loaded value type assertion error
    }
}
```

Now the assignments are cheap because we are assigning pointers (`*sync.Map`)  not structs (`sync.Map`).

---

> Package sync
>
> ```
> import "sync"
> ```
>
> [type Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map)
>
> Map is like a Go map[interface{}]interface{} but is safe for
>   concurrent use by multiple goroutines without additional locking or
>   coordination. Loads, stores, and deletes run in amortized constant
>   time.
>
> The Map type is specialized. Most code should use a plain Go map
>   instead, with separate locking or coordination, for better type safety
>   and to make it easier to maintain other invariants along with the map
>   content.
>
> The Map type is optimized for two common use cases: (1) when the entry
>   for a given key is only ever written once but read many times, as in
>   caches that only grow, or (2) when multiple goroutines read, write,
>   and overwrite entries for disjoint sets of keys. In these two cases,
>   use of a Map may significantly reduce lock contention compared to a Go
>   map paired with a separate Mutex or RWMutex.
>
> The zero Map is empty and ready for use. A Map must not be copied
>   after first use.
>
> ```
> type Map struct {
>         // contains filtered or unexported fields
> }
> ```
>
> [func (*Map) LoadOrStore](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map.LoadOrStore)
>
> ```
> func (m *Map) LoadOrStore(key, value interface{}) (actual interface{}, loaded bool)
> ```
>
> LoadOrStore returns the existing value for the key if present.
>   Otherwise, it stores and returns the given value. The loaded result is
>   true if the value was loaded, false if stored.

---

> A `sync.Map` must not be copied after first use.

In Go, all arguments and receivers are passed by value, as if by assignment (a copy). For example, `go vet` reports a `sync.Map` copy error,

```
// go vet: variable declaration copies lock value to arg: sync.Map contains sync.Mutex
var m sync.Map
var arg interface{} = m
```

and

```
var map1, map2 sync.Map
// go vet: call of map1.LoadOrStore copies lock value: sync.Map contains sync.Mutex
map1.LoadOrStore("key", map2)
```

Use pointers. For example,

```
    var m sync.Map
    var arg interface{} = &m
```

and

```
    var map1, map2 sync.Map
    map1.LoadOrStore("key", &map2)
```

Comment: are you sure? I thought with maps you couldn't do that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl7mi9QmLns minute 21:31 explains why, or sync.Map behave different?, that's why I didn't pass a pointer in first place

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias: "Can I take the address of a value slot someplace in the bucket in my [plain Go] `map`. In Go, you can't do that." Keith Randall. That's true for Go `sync.Map`s too, They are built on top of a plain Go map protected by a mutex. That's interesting, but it is not relevant to your problem. Why do you think it is?

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias: You pass the address of a mapb struct as a value, which is treated like a uintptr integer and stored in an internal memory bucket. You can't ask for the memory address of the uintptr value storage location. You can pass in the key and the map will find it for you and return the uintptr value as an address to you.

Comment: You should use the race detector to test your program. [The Go Blog: Introducing the Go Race Detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) and [Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html).

Comment: You right! I forgot the fact that sync.Map is actually a struct, not an actually map, thanks!